# Start timer in two clients the same time

Tags: client-server, turn-based, timer, synchronization

I want to create a client/server turned-based game where each player will have 5 seconds in order to play. If extends this time will be other player's turn to play. In order to do this, I have created a timer in both clients. I have created a method to the server that will send a message to both clients to start their timers. When clients will receive the message they will start counting. The problem is that due to the network lag I cannot be sure that both clients started counting in the same time. Is there a way in order to ensure this?

P.S.: When I say "the same time" I mean the same second. I'm not referring in millisec or microsec.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you create a timer on the client, it could be an easy way to cheat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16685/synchronize-turn-based-browser-game (I do not know the programming enviroment you use)

Comment: Mikolaj Marcisz I already have the timer on client, but I need a message from the server in order to make it start counting... So, my problem is that if one of two clients has a lag will receive in different time the message to start it's counter. My clients are on android and my server is in java

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm for how NTP handles network lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your current solution will likely start both timers within 1 second of eachother, probably even within a few hundred milliseconds. Getting this more accurate is a difficult problem to solve with certainty, but you can get it "close enough" for games, although it's still not easy. I would also note that timing mechanisms on two different machines may not always match, so either read up on that, or experiment with your method. I had problems where one machine's Timer object would run faster than the exact same code on a slower machine.

To sync the start-time of timers on two different machines, I would go about this in a few steps:

1. Use a time sync protocol like [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to get the clocks in sync
2. The server would send out a message to indicate a future time that would indicate when to start the game. This must be far enough in the future to allow for lag hiccups.
3. When the future date is hit, both clients start

---

### How NTP works (roughly):

One of your machines will act as the authoritative clock (likely your server). By clock, I simply mean some method to measure the passing of time, it does not have to be your wall clock. In games, "time" is often measured from the start of the game.

**The problem:**
If your server sends the current time to the clients, they will receive this information after some period of time (~[RTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time) / 2) and the server's time will have moved forward already. It's impossible to know what the Round Trip Time (RTT) will be for any given packet. So how can the client's time ever match the servers exactly?

**The solution:**
It can't match exactly, but you can get it close by measuring how long it takes for packets to get between the server and client and use that to adjust the time sent from the server. So, the server will send the current time, then after some unknown delay the client will have what used to be the server's time. The client then sends an acknowledgement to the server, and when the server gets this, it calculates the RTT based on the amount of time that has passed since the first packet, then sends the RTT back to the client where it can be used to adjust the time.

eg:

```
//Server Time is T0
Server sends out T0

-- Packet travels with a delay of 100ms

//Server Time is T100
Client receives T0 from the server
Client sends an acknowledgement to the server  (ACK for short)
Client sets time to T0, even though it is wrong

-- Packet travels with a delay of 100ms

//Server Time is T200, Client time = T100
Server receives ACK and calculates RTT as 200ms (Current Time - Start Time)
Server sends RTT of 200ms to client

//Server Time is T300, Client time = T400
Client receives message from server about RTT being 200ms
Client adjusts clock to T300  (Client Time - (RTT / 2))

// Server Time is T400, Client time = T400
And there was much rejoicing
```

The RTT is usually calculated multiple times and an average is used.

---

So, once the clocks are in sync (roughly), the server can send out a command to start the game at some future time. Both clients should receive this message with ample time to spare, then start their timers at the same real-world time.

Comment: Great! NTP looks like the best solution... If I have synchronized the clocks on clients and server, I can send from the server a timestamp that will define when timer will stop. So, if the difference of the timestamp in the time that the client will get the message from the server is less than the expected, this means that there was a lag. So, that way I can set a tolerance in order to decide if the lag delay is accepted or if I have to send a message to the client that is facing lag problems... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what platform you are using but you should find out if you have access to a time function that returns the number of seconds since January 1st 1970.

IE:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/

With that, you send your start time to the clients who can then figure out total elapsed time.

Otherwise you'll have to do some fancy math to determine average ping time and use that to offset the start time when the client receives a next turn message.

Comment: Clocks on different machines vary wildly. It seems like we'd have a handle on this, but we really don't.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, but as John McDonald said there probably would be a problem in order to synchronize clocks of clients and server... I was closer to the ping approach but it is not accurate because the ping packet can have different network lag than the packet of the message that starts the timer, but I hope this is a rare situation...